# BMX on Bicycles?

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic

I ride most forms of bikes, but mainly BMX.
I understand there is little talk on this Biclyces around BMX. (Search gave me 2 Questions, one which an answer I gave).
(I cant add the new tag BMX, as im still <150 rep)

Q1 - Are BMX questions encouraged here?

Q2 - If yes, can we encourage other BMX'ers to contribute here (how, we can solve in another Q).

I think BMX would also have a lot to contribute to overall questions on this site.  You can't really argue that BMX bikes will be the most punished (in terms of stress) out of all the bike types, hence some of the new frame designs/technologies emerging out of BMX may be relevant to other bike disciplines.

Comment: After 10 years, we now have a steady stream of "identify-my-bike" questions, more than half of which are BMX.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hi Simon - "BMX talk" (i.e. chitchat) probably isn't encouraged, but BMX Questions (and Answers) are.

People may run into on/off topic issues if their questions are related to things like location of good BMX parks, or how to execute particular BMX tricks. But then, if its OK to ask how to [clean up after a commute to the office](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34/commuting-question-why-is-this-on-topic-or-is-it), is it OK to ask how to execute a neat bunny hop (the only BMX trick I know) ?

There is a bmx tag now: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bmx

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my Q, "BMX talk" was a bad use of words.

Comment: I would say asking how to do a trick is a valid question. 
There maybe some subjectivity over the "correct" answer, but I think the overall rating will depict which answer is the most useful for someone wanting the Q answered.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with you. As always, a well framed question invites good answers. Ask one to see what happens...

Answer (score 5):

I think it would be nice to ask how to learn a certain trick. Also, I think bmx bikes have seen the greatest progression in technology over the last 5 years than any other action sport, ever! So, there will be room for lots of questions simply on the new ideas different companies are coming out with.

However, opinionated questions like "Who is your favorite rider?" or "Are X-Games killing bmx?" should be closed with the quickness.

Answer (score 5):

BMX should definitely be encouraged here!

This site should be about any and all types of bicyles.   The tagging system allows users (riders?) of all types to co-exist and not get in each others way.  It even allows you to 'Ignore' certain tags if you really really don't want to see that content.  Only ride road bikes and couldn't give a crap about BMX?  No problem, just add 'BMX' to your Ignored tags.  See the 'Prefs' tab on your User page to do this.

The issue of 'community boundaries' has been explored *at length* :

- [Factionalism - Site or Tag/](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/factionalism-site-or-tag/)
- [Merging Season](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/merging-season/)

But do take DotJoe's advice and keep the questions 'on topic'.
See the StackOverflow [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page for more info.